# SSRS Filter on Expression Value

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm in Studio 2012.  I have a report with 2 datasets.  The reports table is linked to one dataset, and I look up values in the second to basically join the datasets on the fly.

I need to filter the table based on results of one of those look-up fields.  I can filter a tablix on a Field from the dataset, but I can't find a method to filter the data based on one of these calculated fields.  For the purposes of other expressions, I can refer to these calculated fields as ReportItems!MyCalculatedField.Value, but I can't set this as a filter in the tablix properties.  How do I proceed here?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can create look-up fields as calculated fields in dataset1 to join the fields from dataset2. Then you can directly apply filter based on these look-up fields. If it's still not working. Try to join the records on T-SQL query level

Comment: You can add look-up fields as calculated fields with a report, but not within the the dataset itself, so you cannot filter on it.  At least, I haven't found a way to do it.